# how to preload a Serenity properties file configuration executing some java code before

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I've got a project with Serenity properties file configuration and I want to put a security code before to start the test, so at the beginning when I prepare the test, I clean the value like this:

```
...
serenity.timeout=1000
secretVariable=
serenity.verbose.steps=FALSE
...
```

but when I run the test, I want to change the serenity.properties like this:

```
...
serenity.timeout=1000
secretVariable=24C20-00034D2
serenity.verbose.steps=FALSE
...
```

So , my question is, is this possible using a java code and/or maven configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change some non-configuration file settings, I may only provide configuration related to the springboot project, you can set your vm option:

```
--serenity.timeout=1000
--secretVariable=24C20-00034D2
--serenity.verbose.steps=FALSE
```

Or you can modify the args parameter of your launch:

```
 String[] arg=new String[3];
 arg[0]="--serenity.timeout=1000";
 arg[1]="--secretVariable=24C20-00034D2";
 arg[2]="--serenity.verbose.steps=FALSE";
```

This is the method I can think of. I have not tried to use maven to manage these parameter configurations, but I have used maven to manage parameter modules. You can use this method to manage, and it supports .yml and .proerties, I will give you an example, but for the specific usage method, you need to go to the official springboot documentation to find the detailed usage method:

**maven:**

```
<!--Configure maven multi-environment development-->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>enc_dev</id>
        <properties>
            <profile.active>dev</profile.active>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>enc_dev</id>
        <properties>
            <profile.active>dev</profile.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**application.proerties:**

```
spring.profiles.active=@profile.active@
spring.profiles.group.dev=devMVC,devDB
spring.profiles.group.pro=proMVC
```

This way you can easily manage the modules you want and do targeted configuration, hope this helps you.